# Chage font to Times New Roman in pdfLatex

Tags: fonts, pdftex, times

Is there any way to change main font to times new roman in Pdf Latex. I search over internet.  And what I saw was how to change font with xelatex or lualatex, not pdflatex.

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage{newtxtext}` to your document preamble. It won't be Times New Roman though, but a similarly looking version.

Comment: `\usepackage{times}` (for pure text) or `\usepackage{mathptmx}` (for text and math font) will also work.

Comment: To expand on what @Werner says, the glyphs will be 'right' but the font name won't be: names can be legally protected.

Comment: Further expansion on @Werner's comment: Also do `\usepackage{newtxmath}` for matching mathematical symbols if your document contains math.

Comment: @mico `times` is deprecated and should not be used. See l2tabu.

Comment: @cfr - All that the `times` package really does is to run `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}`, and similar commands to set the sans serif default to `Helvetica` and the teletype default to `Courier`. As I tried to indicate in the initial comment, the `times` package is OK if (and only if...) if the document is pure text, no math.

Comment: @Mico It does not scale the fonts appropriately. So it is not equivalent to the recommended settings even for documents which contain no maths. The recommendation is to scale Helvetica at .90 to match Times and Courier.

Comment: @cfr I know `times` is deprecated, but in my case I need only the text to be in Times, while the math still in CMR. How to do that with a non-obsolete package?

Comment: @JimRaynor That will look very odd.... But you would be best advised to ask a new question. You can do it if you really must do it by scaling Helvetica and loading Times and Courier by hand. But it is still going to look peculiar with maths in CM.

Comment: Not strange at all, I'm familiar with IEEE style, which they use Times for text and CMR for math. For my question, simply use \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}

Answer (score 12):

`\usepackage{times}` it works for me.

## Update:

It is better to use `\usepackage{mathptmx}` because `times` is obsolete according CTAN:

The pack­age is now ob­so­lete, re­placed by the math­ptmx pack­age, which sup­ports Times Ro­man text and (mostly) match­ing math­e­mat­ics.

Comment: From [CTAN's `times` package page](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/times): `The pack­age is now ob­so­lete, re­placed by the math­ptmx pack­age, which sup­ports Times Ro­man text and (mostly) match­ing math­e­mat­ics.`

Comment: @PaulGessler great! I am using an old version of Ubuntu and I was using an old version of TexLive. I will update the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, mathptmx doesn't have `bold` (italic) math fonts. To have bold mathfonts, one must use `newtxfonts` or the commercial `Math Times Pro2`.

Comment: Sorry but I already change my font from default miktex font. But I  forget the step. What I remember is I uncomment some line in a file under miktex directory.

Comment: Strange. I love the text to be in Times (as required by faculty) but the math stays in computer modern. mathptmx changes everything to Times...

Comment: Apparently mathptmx is also obsolete. Now newtxtext is the one to go with it seems.